# How to mimic MATLAB/Simulink relay behavior?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to mimic the behavior of MATLAB's Simulink [relay](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/relay.html) block with just MATLAB code.

My code is as follows (not familiar with persistent variable? [click](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/coder/examples/working-with-persistent-variables.html)) :

```
function out = fcn(u,delta)
persistent y;

if isempty(y)
   y = 0;
end

if u >= delta
    y = 1;
elseif u <= -delta
    y = 0;
end

out = y;
```

When I look to the output and compare with the real relay block I see :

[image]

Where does the difference come from?

Both blocks insert the same sample time, does the relay block have something extra to show the discontinuity?

[Simulink block diagram download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20782274/relay.mdl)

Comment: how much is the sample time for the relay you are programming? I assume you see kind of response to the commands.

Comment: The `MATLAB function` block inherts the sample time of the solver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about this explanation, maybe somebody can support it.

The `MATLAB function` Block does not support **Zero-Crossing Detection**, the `Relay` Block does. That means the latter knows in advance, when your sine will reach the threshold `delta` and sets the output accordingly to the correct time. The `MATLAB function` Block needs **2** or more steps to detect the slope (respectively the crossing of the threshold). So from one step to another it realizes that the condition for the new output was set and updates the output and you get a ramp, not a step.

`C/C++ S-Function`s do have **Zero-Crossing Detection** - though it seems [quite complicated](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/simulink/sfg/zero-crossings.html).

Comment: This could be the very case indeed yes. Didn't thought of that at first. Hopefully someone can verify this, but my guess for right now is that you are correct.